# Expected value of joint normal probability

Tags: probability-theory

I'm trying to understand the solution to the problem:

Let $f_{XY}$ be the PDF of the random variables $X,Y$. Suppose that
$$f_{X|Y}(x|y)=\frac{f_{XY}(x,y)}{\int f_{XY}(x,y) dx}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi y^2}}exp(-\frac{x^2}{2y^2})$$

Let $\phi_1$ and $\phi_2$ be the characteristic functions of $XY$ and $X|Y|$. Calculate $\phi_3(t)=\frac{\phi_1(t)}{\phi_2(t)}.$

Here's the solution:

[image]

I was wondering why $E[P(-XY\leq x|Y)|Y<0]=E[P(XY\leq x|Y)|Y<0]$.

Answer (score 0):

$X\sim N(0,Y^2)$ means that for $Z\sim N(0,1)$  independent of $Y$ then $X=|Y|Z.$ Let us prove that
$$Y|Y|Z\sim Y^2Z\ \  (*).$$ To this end define the function $s(a)=-1$ if $a<0$, $s(a)=1$ if $a>0$ and $s(0)=0$ and observe that $s(ab)=s(a)s(b).$  We have
$$s(Y|Y|)=s(Y),\ s(Y|Y|Z)=s(Y|Y|)s(Z)=s(Y)s(Z), $$
$$s(Y^2)=s(|Y|),\ s(Y^2Z)==s(|Y|)s(Z) $$
Finally define $p=\Pr(Y<0), \ q=\Pr(Y=0),\ r=\Pr(Y>0)$ and let us compute the laws of $s(Y)s(Z)$ and $s(|Y|)s(Z).$ They are the same since
$$\Pr(s(Y)s(Z)=-1)=(p+r)/2=\Pr(s(|Y|)s(Z)=-1),\ \ \Pr(s(Y)s(Z)=1)=(p+r)/2=\Pr(s(|Y|)s(Z)=1),\ \Pr(s(Y)s(Z)=0)=q=\Pr(s(|Y|)s(Z)=0).$$ Since the three variables $Y,$ $s(Z)$ and $|Z|$ are independent, then (*) is proved (and the corresponding characteristic functions are equal).

Comment: why does $X=|Y|Z$ and not $X=YZ$?

Comment: and why $Pr(()()=−1)=(+)/2$?

Comment: $\sqrt{Y^2}=|Y|.$ For the second question, analyse the two possible cases $s(Y)=-1,$$  s(Z)=1$ (probability $p/2$) and $s(Y)=1,$$  s(Z)=-1$ (probability $r/2$).

Answer (score 0):

The solution proves that $XY$ and $X|Y|$ have the same distribution. To show this, it is enough to show that for all $y \in \mathbb{R}$, $XY$ and $X|Y|$ have the same distribution conditional on $Y = y$. This is because $P(XY \in A) = E(P(XY \in A \mid Y))$. Conditional on $Y = y$, we have $XY = Xy \sim N(0, y^2)y = N(0, y^4)$  and $X|Y| = X|y| \sim N(0, y^2)|y| = N(0, y^2 |y|^2) = N(0, y^4)$.